# Why can you reference a variable before declaring it in a function property of an object?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm looking for an explanation of why and how this is working

```
const someObj = {
    test: () => callback()
}

const callback = () => console.log("how?")

someObj.test()
```

**`output: how?`**

and this is not

```
const someObj = {
    test: callback()
}

const callback = () => console.log("how?")

someObj.test
```

**`output: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'callback' before initialization`**

Comment: At the time `someObj` is defined (in the first case), there isn't anything actually trying to call `callback` in that moment. But in the second case, you are trying to call it before it's defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you are assigning a function to the property test. It doesn't try to call callback until you call it. By the time you do call it callback has been defined. Try calling test before you define callback and you will see if also fails.

In your second example you are trying to assign the result of calling callback to the property test, but seeing callback hasn't been defined yet you get the error.